# Send image in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I want to send a message via email in which the alert and image will be sent using thymeleaf, but I do not want to send it in the implementation method of sending the message, since I cannot make changes to this image in any way, can I add an image to the html code? I try to add an image to the html code, the image does not open and I can't do anything with it, I want the image to appear and I could transfer text to it

```
  public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message,String content) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
    mimeMessage.setSubject(subject);
    mimeMessage.setContent(content, "HTML5");
    MimeMessageHelper helper;
    helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true);
    helper.setFrom(username);
    helper.setTo(emailTo);
    helper.setText(message,true);
```

//        FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(new File("src/main/resources/templates/image/valayev.jpg"));
//        helper.addInline("valyaev", file);

```
    mailSender.send(mimeMessage);
```

[image: my email]

[image: email-template]

Comment: Do you have an external server where you host the picture or do you want to inline the picture?

Comment: image is in static / image

Comment: Do you have checked that the image loads when you access its URL (from the internet) in a web browser and that Thymeleaf creates the right URL in the HTML code (like out put it on the console or in a file instead of an e-mail)?

Comment: that is, is the address to the image written correctly? If I understood the question correctly, then yes, let

Comment: If you open the html through the development environment in the browser, then this photo appears